# ways to define a global method in ruby

Tags: ruby, global

I'm writing a small gem, and I want to define a DSL-like method, pretty much the same as the `desc` and `task` methods in **Rake**.

Rake defines them as private methods in the `Rake::DSL` module and then

```
self.extend Rake::DSL
```

to mix the module into the main object? (I'm a newbie and go ahead laugh if I'm wrong)

what are the benefits by doing so? is it because making these methods private can prevent any other objects to use them (that is, to prevent something like `some_obj.desc`) ?

what if I define the methods in `Kernel`

```
module Kernel
  private

  include Rake::DSL
end
```

Is there any difference?

Comment: BTW, you have a good question, it is nice to see people who wants to make sense of Rube metaprogramming and not simple '.. or I cannot load the gem' :)

Comment: Oh, I was writing my answer so long, that you changed your example of defining a method in Kernel in the meantime. ;-) The previous one was better - now it is not clear what difference you are talking about.

Comment: @Tao, I made a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383656/when-should-i-use-class-object-class-module-module-kernel-and-nothing); maybe it can be useful to you.

Comment: Hi, Arsen7! I read your answer and understand what you mean. Thank you! I'm really talking about the difference between making the methods singleton private instance methods of the main object and making them private instance methods of Object class.

Comment: Thank you Sony Santos! Very helpful link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to extend the answer given by bor1s, about the *private* methods:

In ruby you have "private" and "protected" methods. What bor1s says, is correct when talking about "protected" methods. Declaring a method "private" additionally prevents *other instances of the same class* from using the method.

When you call a "private" method, you cannot use a dot in front of it - you cannot even use `self.`, even though using or omitting `self` has usually the same effect.

```
class Xyzzy
  private
  def foo
    puts "Foo called"
  end

  public
  def do_it
    foo       # <= Is OK
    self.foo  # <= raises NoMethodError
  end
end

Xyzzy.new.do_it
```

If you change 'private' to 'protected' in the code above, no error will be raised.

**And about modules:**

The final result of defining a method in `Kernel` and extending `Kernel` with the method defined in some module is the same: in both cases the method is global.

Using a module is just a little more elegant, as it groups *your* changes in one place, but I would say it's a matter of personal taste.

Usually you do not include methods in Kernel or Object (as it may be a little dangerous), but you include (or extend) a specific class or object which needs these methods, and in this case you *need* your methods grouped in a module.

Even Rake in version 0.9.0 stopped including the DSL commands in Object:

> == Version 0.9.0
>
> - *Incompatible* *change*: Rake DSL commands ('task', 'file', etc.)  are
>     no longer private methods in Object.  If you need to call 'task :xzy' inside
>     your class, include Rake::DSL into the class.  The DSL is still available at
>     the top level scope (via the top level object which extends Rake::DSL).

Comment: Nice post, I just had not enough time to answer more detailed :)

Comment: @bor1s: **Bis dat qui cito dat** _(He gives twice who gives promptly)_ ;-)))

Comment: Yeah, sure :) and I think: Docendo discimus (We learn by teaching) ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. I like the latter part about module very much. and Thanks for the note from Rake 0.9.0

Comment: by the way, `self.extend Rake::DSL` is Rake 0.9+'s code, just for other people's reference

Answer (score 5):

If you define private method in `Kernel` module it will be available in the whole project. You will also rewrite `desc` method that project use to define rake task. But if you write your methods in your submodule and then extend it in superclass or some module - you can easily write any kind of DSL lang like you might saw in `Rake` or `RSpec`.
P.S. Making methods `private` prevents other moludes or classes (but not subclasses) to use them (but not owerwrite) - I mean module nesting hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks, but what I really what to ask is, if I were the author of Rake, is it any different if I mix the module `Rake::DSL` into `Kernel`, instead of extending the main object?

Comment: `Kernel` module included in `Object` - it's mean that all `instanse` methods of `Kernel` become instance methods of Object (I am not sure about Kernel singleton methods), so it will be better to extend `main` object (instance of `Object` class) to have `desc` or `task` singleton methods

Comment: Yes, that is the difference. The difference is between making the methods singleton private instance methods of the main object and making them private instance methods of Object class. Thank you again!